# Multiple definition of 'initialize_idt'

Tags: c, syntax, syntax-error, multiple-definition-error

In the same line I get two errors:

> /path/idt.c:15: multiple definition of 'initialize_idt'

and

> /path/idt.c:15: first defined here

and I'm baffled as to why this might be. I'm declaring in the .h, defining in the .c, and calling in another .c. Every example I've seen doesn't properly #include, but I don't see a problem in my implementation.

```
/***idt.c***/
#include "idt.h"
#include "x86_desc.h"

void initialize_idt(){
     //code
}
/*********/


/***idt.h***/
#ifndef _IDT_H
#define _IDT_H

#include "types.h"

void initialize_idt(void);

#endif
/*********/


/***kernel.c***/
#include "idt.h"
#include "x86_desc.h

void entry(){
    initialize_idt();
}
/*********/
```

EDIT:
The code is very long, it would be a lot to post all at once. I tried changing _IDT_H to a long random sequence and that doesn't seem to fix the problem. grep -rnwe 'initialize_idt' returns:

```
idt.c:7:/* initialize_idt              adding this to fix highlighting->*/
idt.c:15:void initialize_idt(){
idt.h:14:void initialize_idt(void);
Binary file idt.o matches
kernel.c:141:    initialize_idt();
Binary file kernel.o matches
```

Comment: If you're on Linux or something else Unix-like, try `nm --defined-only` on all the object and library files you're trying to link into a program.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but more critically, please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  The line numbers in the error messages don't correspond to the source code you show, so what you've created isn't an MCVE.  It might help if you showed the compilation command line that generates the message.  It's behaving a bit as if you've used `#include "idt.c"` twice inside a source file, though that seems a trifle improbable.  It's one way you could get the message you show, though.  Until you show an MCVE, no-one is likely to be able to help.

Comment: You could show the result of `grep -n idt idt.c idt.h kernel.c` and that might help.  This is deliberately looking for less than the entire word.